# how to fetches column contents of txt by java

Tags: java, io, filereader

```java
String pathname = "F:\\Calibration.txt";
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(pathname);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] split = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(split[0]);
        }
```

This code could fetches the contents of the first column
but columns are not fixed. 
i want to -- automatically fetch data for each column by number of columns 
 not use fix number like this split[fixNumber]

```
27311,28841,30577,31583,0
26401,28046,30234,31255,50
25495,27263,29891,30926,100
24594,26494,29548,30597,150
23696,25737,29206,30269,200
```

this is the content of Calibration.txt

expected output:

```
27311 26401 25495 24594 23696
```

the colmun is not fixed , i dont want use split[0] or (split[1] split[2]...)

---

its my new code:

```java
  List<String> list = new ArrayList();
  String pathname = "F:\\Calibration.txt";
  try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(pathname);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) 
{
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
       }

       for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
           System.out.println(i);
                for(String a : list){
                    String[] regex = a.split(",");
                    System.err.println(regex[i]);

                }
            }
```

Comment: After you split the line, the array would have a size based on the regex you supplied to the split method. The array size will give you the number of columns in a particular line. I think you can then access any column based on the size.

Comment: @uneq95 i dont know how to use, i try to use  for (int i = 0 ; i < split.length(); i ++) { print(split[i])  }. it fetches the content of line

Comment: From your expected output, it seems like you need the first column itself from each line, right? split[0] gives you the right answer, doesn't it? you just don't want to hardcode the index number

Comment: yes, but... if i dont know how many colmuns it has, i should not use hardcode

Comment: so why not apply a check to the size of the split array. print only if split.length>0. how about that. to get the first column you will need to use the integer 0. your code could be like `if(split.length > 0) System.out.println(split[0])`

Comment: what does this mean-"i want to -- automatically fetch data for each column by number of columns "?

Comment: thanks, i find a way to solve this problem

Comment: please tell us the solution you wanted

Comment: em... my english is bad.. i mean i want to output each column not use hardcode

Comment: so what code did you finally come up with?

Comment: update , maybe u can optimize it !

Comment: Why two loops?? if you have 10 lines in the file and the 10th line only has 5 columns, your code will throw an exception of array index out of bounds because you would be accessing regex[9], where regex.length is 5

Comment: using two loops makes no sense

Comment: i hve no idea..

Comment: try to run the program, you will get the idea

Comment: is there a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets suppose you have read the file and stored all the lines in an `ArrayList` as done by you.

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList();
  String pathname = "F:\\Calibration.txt";
  try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(pathname);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) 
{
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
       }

 }
```

If your first line is

> 27311,28841,30577,31583,0

then in this line, value of column 1 (or index 0) is 27311,

column 2 =28841,

column 3 =30577 and so on..

If you want the ith( or i-1 index) column of the nth( or n-1 index) line, you need to do the following:

```
String row = list.get(n-1); //row n
String[] columns = row.split(",");//this gives you the columns
//Now access any column
String col1 = columns[0];
String colI = columns[i-1];
```

Now, as per your expected output you want the 1st column of all the lines. Hence, you need to iterate on the list, split them and get the first column.

```
//iterate the list
for(String line : list){
    String[] columns = line.split(",");
    String col0 = columns[0];
    System.out.println("column 1 : "+col0);
}
```

If you only want the first column from each line, another way could be to delete the other columns and commas using regex.

```
//iterate the list
for(String line : list){
    String col0 = line.replaceFirst("\\s*,.*", "");
    System.out.println("column 1 : "+col0);
}
```

To print all the columns, you additionally need to traverse the columns array as shown below.

```
//iterate the list
    for(String line : list){
        String[] columns = line.split(",");
        for(int i =0; i<columns.length; i++)
             System.out.println("column "+ i +": "+columns[i]);
    }
```

Comment: how to output each column

Comment: i want to use the vertical way to output each column

Comment: You have the data. You can print it anyway you want.